# C Linked List from Array

Tags: c, arrays, list

In the function, I created an array of size two which will hold two PolyTerms. Then, within the function, i created a List. After that, i want to pass the array elements into the List as linked list.

I'm getting an error after the if statement
head->next = nodePtr; (Bad Access).

Thanks.

Part of my code:

```
struct Fraction {
    int num;
    int denom;
};

struct PolyTerm {
    int ex;
    struct Fraction coe;
};
typedef struct PolyTerm PTerm;
typedef struct PolyTerm* PTermPtr;

struct PolyListNode {
    PTermPtr termAddr;
    struct PolyListNode* next;
};
typedef struct PolyListNode PList;
typedef struct PolyListNode* PNodeAddr;
typedef struct PolyListNode* PolyList;

PolyList sortPoly(void);

PolyList sortPoly() {

    int arraySize = 2;
    int i = 0;

    //Array of PTermPtr. Each element holds ex, num and denom.
    //Populating 2 elements for arrayTerm

    PTermPtr arrayTerm;
    arrayTerm = (PTermPtr) malloc(arraySize);
    ((arrayTerm) + 0)->ex = 2;
    ((arrayTerm) + 0)->coe.num = 2;
    ((arrayTerm) + 0)->coe.denom = 2;

    ((arrayTerm) + 1)->ex = 3;
    ((arrayTerm) + 1)->coe.num = 2;
    ((arrayTerm) + 1)->coe.denom = 2;

    PNodeAddr nodePtr; //To create nodes
    PolyList head = 0; //New List
    PNodeAddr current; //To store Address of List Head
    current= head; //Store address of head of list

    while (i < arraySize) {

        nodePtr = (PNodeAddr) malloc(sizeof(PList));
        nodePtr->termAddr = (arrayTerm + i);
        nodePtr->next = 0;

        if (current == 0) {
            head->next = nodePtr; //ERROR. Bad Access
        } else {
            while (current != 0) {
                current = current->next;
            }
            current->next = nodePtr;
        }
        i++; 
    }
    free (arrayTerm);
    return head;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to write it so that nobody else has to.
Use the debugger.

Comment: if you eliminate the many typedef's and write out each of the struct references, the code would be much easier to follow/understand for both us and (later) you

Comment: head should have pointed the first allocated node that's why you're getting an error.

Comment: in C, the returned value from malloc() and family of functions should not be cast.  However, it should be checked (!= NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: 0) `arrayTerm = (PTermPtr) malloc(arraySize);` --> `arrayTerm = (PTermPtr) malloc(arraySize*sizeof(PTerm));`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY sorry, i fixed it. I messed it up when i cut down my code. Now i'm able to run it but the list is giving me 2097200/1x3  instead of the expected 2/2x2+2/2x3(there isnt an issue with my display function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just think about what is going on the first time the code goes thru the loop:

```
PolyList head = 0; //New List
```

Head is now 0 (or null).

```
current= head; //Store address of head of list
```

Current and head are now 0

```
    if (current == 0) {
```

It is.

```
        head->next = nodePtr; //ERROR. Bad Access
```

Try to access head which is 0 and null.  you are accessing null

---

It should also be noted the sizes you pass in to malloc are wrong.  You are passing in the size of the arrays you want to create not the size of memory needed.

For example you are need a 2 element array of type mytype you want this code:

```
 newarray = malloc(2 * sizeof(mytype));
```

then

```
 newarray[0]
```

and

```
 newarray[1]
```

have space for a mytype.

Comment: I edited head->next=nodePtr to head=nodePtr and allocated memory as you said. Now it runs but when i display the returned list. it's showing 2097200/1x3 instead of 2/2x2+2/2x3. i set up my display menu to display this way but it's displaying 2097200/1x3

Comment: I already fixed that part to arrayTerm = (PTermPtr) malloc(2 * sizeof(PTerm)); Changed         head->next = nodePtr; //ERROR. Bad Access to head = nodePtr and  i also changed  current->next = nodePtr; to current = nodePtr; I'm not getting back the correct linked list.

Comment: @Denominator - there is no way to know what is wrong -- you could debug it yourself or post a new question with that code.

Comment: Solved. I was missing   head->next = current; after the while loop to update the head. I don't know how to debug. I need to learn how. THank you.!! and the         current = head; should go inside the while loop

Comment: That is awesome @Denominator congrats!